# How to set a space as separator for to_csv()? - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I need to save a dataframe as a csv knowing that I need to read that csv file with a  `delim_whitespace=True` option in another script?

Here's an example of what I am trying to do -> The dataframe `df` I'm working with is the following:

```py
    id  var1        var2
0   0   0.000000    0.000000
1   1   0.000000    0.000000
2   2   0.000000    0.000000
```

I want to save it with a `delim_whitespace` as a delimiter so I tried:

```py
df.to_csv('df_file.csv', delim_whitespace=True) #does not work
df.to_csv('df_file.csv', sep=r"\s+")            #cannot be opened with a pd.read_csv('df_file.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
df.to_csv('df_file.csv', sep='\t')              #cannot be opened with a pd.read_csv('df_file.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
df.to_csv('df_file.csv', sep=' ')               #cannot be opened with a pd.read_csv('df_file.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
df.to_csv('df_file.csv', sep='    ')            #cannot be saved because sep needs one character apparently
```

What separator can I use so I can then read that file with the `delim_whitespace=True` option?

Comment: What is the issue with the 4th option?
'df.to_csv('df_file.csv', sep=' ') '

Comment: @Quixotic22 technically the third option allows me to save my file but I really need to open it in another script with ```pd.read(file, delim_whitespace=True)``` not with a ```pd.read(file, sep=' ')```

Comment: @I.M. do you mean `pd.read_csv`? because `pd.read()` doesn't exist. Wich version of pandas are you using? Also `pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True)` will work with `df.to_csv('df_file.csv', sep=' ')` just fine. What exactly is your error? Do you by chance have values in your dataframe that have whitespaces alread?  Like `var1 = "stack overflow"`

Comment: Oh yes my mistake @Andreas I meant to write ```pd.read_csv()```, my apologies for that. I did try to read the file saved with ```df.to_csv('df_file.csv', sep=' ')``` with ```pd.read_csv('df_file', delim_whitespace=True)``` but it raised an error ```ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 66 fields in line 16080, saw 67``` (which I find strange because I only have floats and integers in ```df```)

Comment: @I.M. this means you should look into line 16080 of your csv. If it is not too long, load it in excel or something else. Expected 66 fields means up to that point you had 66 columns, now in this one line you have 67, this is only possible if there is an additional whitespace, which should'nt be there. Please see my answer, I also showed an alternative to skip those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full save/read example:

**Sample data:**

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'id': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}, 'var1': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0}, 'var2': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0}}
df_save = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

**Code:**

`index=False` otherwise after loading the index will be added as another separate column.

```
p = r'C:\test.csv'
df_save.to_csv(p, sep=' ', index=False)
df_read = pd.read_csv(p, sep=' ')
```

**Output:**

```
   id  var1  var2
0   0   0.0   0.0
1   1   0.0   0.0
2   2   0.0   0.0
```

---

If you expirience the error: `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 66 fields in line 16080, saw 67`

This means you have at least in that line one more whitespace than there should be. You can now either inspect the file with some reader, e.g. Pycharm or even Excel and clean that line.

Or you can simply skip bad lines like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('df_file.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
df.to_csv("output.csv",sep=' ')
```

to save the file.

To read the file:

```
df=pd.read_csv("output.csv",sep=' ')
```

You will get 'Unnamed: 0' as a column name,
To deal with that just run:

```
df.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'],inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't use delim_whitespace in to_csv. Check the [documnetation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

---

```py
entries=[[0,1,2],[0.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.]]
df=pd.DataFrame(dictt,columns=['id', 'var1', 'var2'])
df
```

```
Output:
    id  var1    var2
0   0.0     1.0     2.0
1   0.0     0.0     0.0
2   0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Save using `sep=' '` and checking the resulting file with cat.

```py
df.to_csv('temp.csv',sep=' ')
!cat tt.csv
```

```
Output:
 id var1 var2
0 0 0.0 0.0
1 1 0.0 0.0
2 2 0.0 0.0
```

Can read it then using the `delim_whitespace=True`

```py
pd.read_csv('temp.csv',delim_whitespace=True)
```

```
Output:
    id  var1    var2
0   0.0     1.0     2.0
1   0.0     0.0     0.0
2   0.0     0.0     0.0
```